# libmysqlclient.18.dylib memory leak

Tags: c++, mysql, memory-leaks

`PROBLEM`: What's the cause of the memory leaks?

`SITUATION`:
I've build a simple command line program using C++ together with MySQL using the MySQL C API

The problem is, the program has many "minor" memory leaks from the object `malloc xx bytes"` with xx ranging from a few bytes to 8 kb. All of the leaks links to the library `libmysqlclient.18.dylib`.

I've already removed all the `mysql_free_result()` from the code to see if that was the problem, but its still the same.

My MySQL code mainly consists of simple code like:

to connect:

```
MYSQL *databaseConnection()
{
    // declarations
    MYSQL *connection = mysql_init(NULL);

    // connecting to database
    if(!mysql_real_connect(connection,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0))
    {
        std::cout << "Connection error: " << mysql_error(connection) << std::endl;
    }
    return connection;
}
```

executing a query:

```
MYSQL_RES *getQuery(MYSQL *connection, std::string query)
{
    // send the query to the database
    if (mysql_query(connection, query.c_str()))
    {
        std::cout << "MySQL query error: " << mysql_error(connection);
        exit(1);
    }
    return mysql_store_result(connection);
}
```

example of a query:

```
void resetTable(std::string table)
{
    MYSQL *connection = databaseConnection();
    MYSQL_RES *result;

    std::string query = "truncate table " + table;
    result = getQuery(connection, query);

    mysql_close(connection);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Opening a new connection for every query (like you're doing in `resetTable()`) is incredibly wasteful. What you really want to do is open a single connection when the application starts, use that for everything (possibly by storing the connection in a global), and close it when you're done.

To answer your question, though: You need to call [`mysql_free_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-free-result.html) on result sets once you're done with them.

Comment: The example above is just a, like i said, example. I don't open a new connection for every query :p Anyway, I already tried putting `mysql_free_result()` after every result set but it's still leaking. In another thread I've read about using `mysql_library_end()` after closing the connection. Still the same amount of leaks...

Comment: damn, after breaking down my program code for code i found out you actually have to free **every** single set of result. thanks duskwuff!